# Switch selection between button and text field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing a piece of software in Java, with a GUI programmed using swing. The user has to do this two operations in a loop:

1. write some words in a text field (let's call it A) and press Enter
2. click a button (let's call it B)

After Enter is pressed, some other fields show some data. After the button is clicked, all text fields are cleared and the procedure restarts. The text field to fill in is always A and the button to click is always B. This is what I would like to implement:

1. After the text field is filled and Enter is pressed, the button is somehow selected so that if the user presses Enter again the button is clicked
2. After the button is pressed, the text field is selected and in "write mode", so that the user can immediately start typing

What is the easiest method to implement this? Below I'm reporting what I have already tried.

---

I tried this to make the button selected immediately after Enter is pressed in the text field:

```
this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(ButtonNextQuestion);
```

but when I press Enter, it is registered both by the text field and the button and I cannot see intermediate data.

I tried also with these lines:

```
ButtonNextQuestion.requestFocus();
ButtonNextQuestion.setSelected(true);
```

in this case everything seems working, but when I press enter the button is not clicked.

Comment: Try adding a listener to the button.. when user presses enter and the button is selected (simple if statements), then ButtonNextQuestion.doClick()

Comment: Thank you AdamK! You were right! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to AdamK!

The focus to the button was given like this:

```
ButtonNextQuestion.requestFocus();
ButtonNextQuestion.setSelected(true);
```

I had to add a listener to the button like this:

```
private void ButtonNextQuestionKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){                                              
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {//ENTER pressed: click
        ButtonNextQuestion.doClick();
    }
}
```

Then again to automatically select and make the text field ready to be written I used:

```
TextYourAnswer.requestFocus();
```